# Braintree Virtual Terminal Backend User Role

Tags: magento2, user-roles, braintree

How can I enable the Braintree Virtual Terminal that is under the Sales tab in the backend?  I only see it for a user role that has access to everything. There needs to be an option after Transactions in the resource section.  [image: Role Resources]

Answer (score 0):

After looking through the menu.xml file under the Braintree module, I figured out you have to give the user access to Sales:Create and then the Braintree Virtual Terminal will be available for that user role.